# Using the each method on my view's instance variable returns NoMethodError, undefinded .each method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working towards generating a list into my view. When attempting to loop through my @residents instance variable, I receive the error

NoMethodError in Admins#show

Showing /Users/myCPU/rails_projects/whizcharts/app/views/residents/index.html.erb where line #3 raised:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h1>Resident Profiles</h1>
2: <ul class="list-residents">
3:  <% @residents.each do |r| %>
4:      <li>
5:          <%= link_to r.fname, r %>
6:      </li>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/admins/show.html.erb
```

I've tried the following...

- Ran rake db:migrate in case that was the issue.
- In my '/controllers/residents_controller' file, I've tried changing

  `@residents = Resident.find(:all) to @residents = Resident.find.all`

Here is my code...

## 'controllers/residents_controller.rb'

```
class ResidentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @residents = Resident.find(:all) 
  end

  def show
    @resident = Resident.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @resident = Resident.new
  end

  def create
    @resident = Resident.new(params[:resident])
    if @resident.save 
      redirect_to @resident, :success => "Your submission was a success"
    else 
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @resident = Resident.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @resdient = Resident.find(params[:id])
    if @resident.update_attributes(params{:resident})
        flash[:success] = "Resident's profile updated"
        sign_in @resident
        redirect_to @resident
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Resident.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Resident deleted"
    redirect_to residents_path
  end

  def _form
    @residents = Resident.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

## 'config/routes.rb'

```
Whizcharts::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  resources :admins, :residents
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  # static_page 
  match '/help',       to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about' ,     to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact',    to: 'static_pages#contact'

  # sign in | sign up
  match '/signup',    to: 'admins#new'
  match '/signin',    to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout',   to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
 .
 .
 .
   match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

## 'views/residents/index.html.erb'

```
<h1>Resident Profiles</h1>
<ul class="list-residents">
    <% @residents.each do |r| %>
        <li>
            <%= r.fname %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

## '/db/schema.rb'

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120722195705) do

  create_table "admins", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "fname"
    t.string   "lname"
    t.string   "soc"
    t.string   "dob"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.text     "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "phone1"
    t.string   "phone2"
    t.datetime "created_at",                               :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                               :null => false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "password"
    t.string   "password_confirmation"
    t.string   "remember_token"
    t.boolean  "super",                 :default => false
  end

  add_index "admins", ["email"], :name => "index_admins_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "admins", ["remember_token"], :name => "index_admins_on_remember_token"

  create_table "residents", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "fname"
    t.string   "lname"
    t.string   "dob"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.string   "soc"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "doc_fname"
    t.string   "doc_lname"
    t.string   "doc_phone1"
    t.string   "doc_phone2"
    t.string   "doc_fax"
    t.string   "doc_email"
    t.string   "guard_fname"
    t.string   "guard_lname"
    t.string   "guard_address"
    t.string   "guard_city"
    t.string   "guard_state"
    t.string   "guard_zip"
    t.string   "guard_phone1"
    t.string   "guard_phone2"
    t.string   "guard_email"
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
  end

end
```

And since the NoMethodError is in Admins#show here's the code for that.

## '/views/admins/show.html.erb'

```
<% provide(:title, @admin.fname + " " + @admin.lname) %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>
                <%= gravatar_for @admin %>
                <%= @admin.fname + " " + @admin.lname %> 
            </h1>
        </section>
        <section class="resident">
            <div class="content">
                <div id="new-resident">
                    <%= link_to 'create a new resident', new_resident_path %>
                </div>
                <div id="list-residents">
                    <%= render :template => 'residents/index' %>
                </div>
            </div><!-- END content CLASS -->
        </section>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Finally, when I remove the each method from my 'views/residents/index.html.erb' file, my browser renders properly. I don't feel as though I have an understanding of how to mix partials from different controllers nor how to properly use instance variables. Any help on this problem as well as providing the topic(s) I should be reading up on (in addition to the rails documentation) are appreciated.

Comment: @residents is set to nil. Do you have any residents in the database?

Comment: I've added 1 resident, but haven't confirmed whether the database accepted it. I did a quick search to find out whether or not there was a rake db command for showing the data in my tables, but so far have come up with nothing. I'll respond again when I can confirm the answer to your question.

Comment: The db is saving the profiles, and with Nils Landt's suggestion my browser is now rendering proplrly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you run into the show action in the Admins controller, not the index action (`NoMethodError in Admins#show`).

Does this still happen if you add `@residents = Resident.find(:all)` under `def show`?

Comment: Yes, when I add @residents = Resident.find(:all) to my 'controllers/admins_controller.rb' file my browser renders properly. I  refrained from this option earlier because I didn't know if it was in bad form. Decoupling and all. Is it not bad form to do this?

Comment: If you don't do any redirects, only one method in your controller will be called anyway, which means if you want to display all residents in the show action and the index action, you will need to have that particular line of code twice in your controller (or put it in a helper method, and have the call to the helper method twice).